# Display "Download failed" message when application is cleared from the recent apps in mobile

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing a project using services from AWS S3 client (Amazon Web Services) . 
I view the contents from my respective bucket.
If the content is a file, Then i use the object of TransferManager and Download the file.
The Download class is of AWS itself. I have written a fragment for downloading.
The problem i am facing is, when i clear the app from the recent applications in my phone while the download is running, then the file isnt downloaded. How and where do i display a toast message :Download failed", when the application is cleared from the recent apps?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for this. When download is in progress you can show the ongoing notification. A nice example is given [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/FileDownloadService.htm)

Comment: Thanks !!! Okay, It means i must use a service for this, right now i have created a fragment for download. It retains the download state during configuration/orientation change. Is that of no use now? Creating a service instead will solve the above issues too? I am new to know these concepts. Thanks again.

Comment: There is no need to create fragment. Check how the chrome download a file.